# How to release an app with multiple payment types based on location

Tags: android, payment

We are currently working on an application that will be released worldwide. One of the requirements the client wants is to only have certain payment types displayed based on where the user is using the application for example if they were from America it would display Paypal, China would display AliPay and Hong Kong would display WeChat Pay.

At the moment i have two ideas. Firstly create different product flavours that include the correct payment types for the country. Then when it comes to releasing the application only target the application to that country.  However, the issue i see with this is that i would have to upload multiple versions of the application each time there is an update.

The other option is to include all of the payment types then when the user opens the app it checks the country code then displays the relevant payment types. The benefits of this is that i would only ever have to upload a single APK. The only downfall is the logic required to work out which payment to show.

Any thoughts would be great!

Comment: I like the second route to include all payment options and create a dynamic application based on the users context - it allows more freedom and flexibility for your user's. Example: let's say someone downloads in one country and frequents traveling to another country where the payment options are varied from the original install.